# How to enable ZTS and install pthreads with php5.4 in centos 7?

Tags: pthreads, centos7, php-5.4, zts

I am using Centos7 with php version 5.4.45 but I m unable to configure pthread.

> Please help me out with some steps to install, configure and compile
>   the pthread library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is meant by *unable*?

Comment: Updated sentence with tag

Comment: Getting error make: *** No rule to make target `/root/php-5.4.36/ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.c', needed by `ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.lo'.  Stop.

Comment: @Rohit check in the `{php_path_on_your_pc}/ext` folder.. see if pthreads folder present.. if not download using wget into the folder from http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps method mentioned on this https://blog.flowl.info/2015/compile-php-5-6-pthreads-mongo-ubuntu/

here they have used php-**5.6.12** version. Change to your requirement